# ¿Porque funciona igual con corchetes y sin corchetes?

Tags: angular4, angular-directivas

Tengo una duda:

```
<p appAttributeDirectives [color]  =  green >
```

Miren el atributo color esta en una directiva que adentro tiene un input que seria el alias y el atributo green es del component.Ts no entiendo porque yo al sacar los corchetes

```
<p appAttributeDirectives color  =  green >
```

igual funciona

y tambien si le agrego comillas al atributo gree igual funciona

```
<p appAttributeDirectives color  =  "green" >
```

en eso tres casos funciona pero no entiendo con que propósito irían esos corchetes y esas comillas si de todas formas igual funcionaria si esos símbolos osea así:

```
<p appAttributeDirectives [color]  =  green >
```

Comment: Por favor, no escribas todo en mayúsculas. ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta? Además, no se está mostrando tu código porque hay que seleccionarlo y presionar el botón `{}`

Answer (score 1):

Las comillas en los atributos de las plantillas de [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) son sólo obligatorias si el texto asignado tiene espacios. Por ejemplo, esto no funcionaría:

```
<tag *ngFor=let item of list>
```

Pero lo normal, por mantener cierta homogeneidad y claridad en el formato, es usar las comillas siempre.

Por otro lado tienes los corchetes:

```
<miComponente [color]="identificador">
```

El código anterior significa que en el componente actual hay un atributo llamado `identificador` y que su valor queda asociado al atributo `color` del componente hijo `miComponente`. Si el valor de `identificador` es modificado en algún momento, también lo será el valor de `color`. En el caso de que el atributo `color` sea un string y no quieras que varíe, puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<miComponente color="green">
```

Pero entonces estás asignando a color el valor `"green"` de manera constante.